# problem in creating - Provisioning Portal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase, provisioning

i'm trying to create an In-App purchase. but i'm facing a problem in creating - Provisioning Portal. 
After creating an APP ID, On the “Configure App ID” screen, i'm unable to get that option “Enable In App Purchase”. what could be the possible error i'm making in the procedure ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be using a * wild card for your APP Id, your app id must be unique in order to use in app purchases and push notification..

Comment: I haven't included *wild card for my APP ID. I have taken care to keep the id unique... what else could be the fault ?